# Residue theorem applied to integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I'm not sure I understood how to apply the theorem.

### $ \int_ 0 ^\infty \frac{dx}{3x^2+4} \ $

where the singular points are $ \frac{2i}{\sqrt3} $  and $ -\frac{2i}{\sqrt3}$.

I proceeded this way (using the complex variable z instead of x):

$\lim_{z \to \frac{2i}{\sqrt3}} (z-\frac{2i}{\sqrt3})  \frac{1}{(z-\frac{2i}{\sqrt3}) (z+\frac{2i}{\sqrt3})} $ 
$= \lim_{z \to \frac{2i}{\sqrt3}} \frac{1}{(z+\frac{2i}{\sqrt3})} = \frac{\sqrt3}{4i}.
$

Now I should multiply the residue by $2\pi i$ , obtaining  $\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\pi$.

Is this correct?

Comment: The residue theorem applies to a closed curve. What closed curve is related to the real integral?

Comment: If you want to check if your result is correct, factoring the $4$ out of the denominator and integrating gives $$\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{3}} \arctan{x} \bigg \lvert_{0}^{\infty}$$

Comment: @Mattos I'm sorry I think I didn't understand how to use this information.

Comment: You asked if your solution was correct, I wanted to point out that one way of checking if your result is true is by using methods other than the residue theorem. Here, you have $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3x^{2} + 4} dx=\frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3x^{2}/4 + 1} dx$$ so setting $y = \frac{\sqrt{3}x}{2} \implies dy=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} dx$ yields $$\frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3x^{2}/4 + 1} dx=\frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \frac{1}{y^{2} + 1} dy=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{3}} \arctan(y) \bigg \lvert_{0}^{\infty}=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{3}} \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - 0\right)$$

Comment: @Mattos Thank you very much! It's clear now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

First, note that

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{3x^2+4}\,dx=\frac12 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{3x^2+4}\,dx$$

Then, use the residue theorem by closing the contour from $z=-R$ to $z=R$ in either the upper-half or the lower-half plane with a semi-circle of radius $R$.  Only one pole will be enclosed.  Let $R\to \infty$.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! So is the final result $\frac{\sqrt3}{4}\pi$. ?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  The answer is $\pi/(4\sqrt3)$.

Comment: I'm probably missing something algebric. Why is the square root on the  denominator?

Comment: You wrote the denominator $3z^2+4=3(z^2+4/3)=3(z+i2/\sqrt3)(z-i2/\sqrt3)$.  You appear to have dropped the factor of $3$.  And $\sqrt 3/3=1/\sqrt3$.

Comment: Ops, my bad. Thank you again, very kind!

Comment: Sure.  Pleased this was useful.